# SimpleMembership with IBM Informix in MVC4.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, informix

I am stuck with SimpleMembership with IBM Informix in MVC4.0 database.

I am facing issue at the moment when "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("OpioCentralDB", "userprofile", "userid", "username", autoCreateTables: true);" method is calling.

Exception is occurred saying "ERROR [42000] [IBM][IDS/UNIX64] The specified table (informix.tables) is not in the database. (-111 ISAM error:  no record found.)"

As per my research Runtime is looking for the table which is required to perform SimplMembership and trying to create it & due to syntax problem failing to do so.

I created required table in DB already, even then I am getting same error!

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have googled many days and came to the conclusion by reading many posts that this seems not possible
because there is syntax difference between MS SQL expressions and informix SQL expression for projecting queries.

The moment SimpleMembership tries to create tables or check existing tables needed for performing Membership; due to syntax differences it fails to create any and jump into error saying The specified table (informix.tables) is not in the database.